# Configure Event Listener in Keycloak

Tags: jboss, listener, wildfly, keycloak

I'm configuring a event listener in KeyCloak in a Wildfly 9.0.1. 
I have created a .jar with two clases, implements a provider like Keycloak explains in his github's example.

In this example, Keycloak people explain it's necessary to register the provider editing "standalone/configuration/standalone.xml" and adding the module to the providers element. 
I code this definition inside the tag "subsystem":

```html
<spi name="eventsListener">
  <provider name="my-event-listener" enabled="true">
    <properties>
      <property name="max" value="100" />
    </properties>
  </provider>
</spi>
```

When I start the server, it gives me a error like this:

```html
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
 at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131)
 at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:350)
 at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:271)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Unknown keycloak-server subsystem tag: spi
 at org.keycloak.subsystem.server.extension.KeycloakSubsystemParser.readElement(KeycloakSubsystemParser.java:55)
 at org.keycloak.subsystem.server.extension.KeycloakSubsystemParser.readElement(KeycloakSubsystemParser.java:39)
 at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
 at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69)
 at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:1199)
 at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_4(StandaloneXml.java:457)
 at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:144)
 at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:106)
 at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
 at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
 at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123)
 ... 3 more

FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

Someone knows what is wrong? I need help.

Thanks you.

Comment: Hi! Anyone can help me??

Comment: What version of keycloak do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must code your definition inside : `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1">`

Comment: The message "Unknown keycloak-server subsystem" present in log does not show that it is already inside ?